# How to minify JS and CSS files in cygwin ?

Tags: javascript, css, cygwin

I am currently using CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW
I looked all over the internet but could not find anything saying how to minify javascript or css files in Cygwin.

I have found some ways to minify by transferring my js input to a website which would do the operation at: http://compressorrater.thruhere.net/, but 
approximately knowing how the minify operation work, I thought that there might be some wuick cygwin command for that.
Does someone have any idea on how this should be done?

Comment: None that I know of. There are plenty of minifcation tools that run in both cygwin and windows. Probably best to pick one of those.

Comment: Thank you AIG. I actually found the following link telling me how to compress Javascript and Css files: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-minify-compress-css-javascript-files-shell-prompt/